# Sorting a list of ArrayList by date in the ArrayList

Tags: java, list, sorting, date, java-ee-7

I have a list of ArrayList, and each arraylist consists of a date and a string. I want to sort the list according to the date in the arraylist. I tried looking for answers but cant find it online. Most of the examples are sorting a list of objects by date. Any suggestions?

```
public List<ArrayList> SuggestionReport() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM SuggestionEntity s");
    List<ArrayList> report = new ArrayList();
    for (Object o : q.getResultList()) {
        suggestionEntity = (SuggestionEntity) o;
        ArrayList suggestion = new ArrayList();
        suggestion.add(suggestionEntity.getSuggestionDate());
        suggestion.add(suggestionEntity.getContent());
        report.add(suggestion);
    }

    return report;
}
```

ps. I want to sort the list before returning the list

Comment: you can query by date.try this sql "SELECT s FROM SuggestionEntity s order by s.suggestionDate desc".the "s.suggestionDate" is your database field .than the result was sort already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need not to write extra code, Just change your query to

```
SELECT s FROM SuggestionEntity s order by  suggestion_date ASC|DESC
```

Where `suggestion_date`  is your column name.

`ASC|DESC`  is order you want, choose `ASC` or `DESC` based on your requirment.

Learn more here about [order by](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-order-by.htm)

Comment: Thanks alot!! But this is applicable to java ejb query as well right?

Comment: Ofcourse, It supports `sql` right ? Syntax might change. But concept is same. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own comparator, and then sort it like following:

```
Collections.sort(list, myComparator);
```